# Rewriting a loop in functional form maintaining object names

Tags: r

I am trying to rewrite the following loop in form of a generalizable funtion:

```
count = 1
for (i in alc) {
  alc[[count]] <- fwildclusterboot::boottest(i, param = "treatment", clustid = "university", B = 9999)
  count = count + 1
}
```

In this code, `alc` is a list of `fixest` regression objects. The point of the code is to replace each component of the list with the wild-cluster-bootstrap estimates of each model, **while maintaining the names of the objects**. It is imperative that the name of the original list remains exactly the same since `broom::glance` will not work otherwise (e.g., using `purrr::map`, or other functional programming methods).

I have tried the following code, although this code does not work properly which surprises me; using `get("alc")[[1]]` in the console seems to give a proper output.

```
boot_estimates <- function(x, count=1) {
## get the name of the input x
  y <- deparse(substitute(x)) 
## replace elements of the name with bootstrapped versions
  for (i in x) {
    get("y")[[count]] <- boottest(i, param = "treatment", clustid = "university", B = 9999) 
    count = count + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Untested, but does `lapply(alc, boottest, param = "treatment", clustid = "university", B = 9999)` not preserve `names(alc)`?

Comment: While this provides output, the problem is that the output has the following attribute in the `call` portion of the list: `boottest.fixest(object = X[[i]], clustid = "university", param = "treatment", B = 9999)` . This makes it impossible to perform a `broom::glance` on this object since `broom::glance` pulls from the `call` object, which in this case is `X[[i]]` which does not exist in the environment.